# "java.lang" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: java, jaxb

I use a certain private library that internally uses JAXB. When the JAXB context is initialized I get an error from the title. This is weird, I always assumed that default java classes (i.e. java.lang.String) have default jaxb mappings. Any ideas on how to approach this issue?

The provider i use is com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.

Comment: You should probably show some code.